# How do I write an async child reaper in Go?

Tags: go, signals, zombie-process

I have some go code like this:

```
cmd = exec.Command(command)
//...
cmd.Run()
func reapChild(cmd) {
    sigc := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigc, syscall.SIGCHLD)
    go func() {
        my_signal := <- sigc
        log.Infof("appstore: reapChildren: got a SIGCHLD signal")
        cmd.Wait()
        signal.Stop(sigc)
    }()
}
```

This reaps the process for a specific spawned child, but I'm looking
for something more generic.

Is there a way to get the PID off my_signal?  I'm looking for something
like the  pid_t wait(int *status) -- golang provides a function
called Wait4 that takes a specific PID.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? goroutines are very cheap.

Comment: What is a child reaper and what is used for ?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unix+reaping+child+processes+definition&t=canonical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, Go's syscall package has this function:

```
func Wait4(pid int, wstatus *WaitStatus, options int, rusage *Rusage) (wpid int, err error)
```

That seems to work for you. From [the BSD man page for `wait(2)`](http://www.manpages.info/freebsd/wait.2.html) (remember that Go was developed partly on Macs!):

> The wait4() call provides a more general interface for programs that
>   need  to wait for certain child processes, that need resource
>   utilization statistics accumulated by child processes, or that
>   require options.  **The  other wait functions are implemented using
>   wait4()**.

By passing the right arguments, you can achieve what you want with `Wait4`. For example, if you don't want to wait for a specific child:

> If pid is -1, the call waits for any child process.

You can find the rest of the information you need in the man page.

Comment: Notice that wait4() is in the syscall package. A program that uses parts of the syscall package is non-portable as the syscall package has different contents on every OS.

Comment: Thx for the reply fuzxxl, but what do you mean by "parts of the syscall package"?